# Составить программу, которая определяет, является ли четырёхугольник с вершинами в точках (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) и (x4,y4) ромбом

Tags: javascript, pascal, геометрия, pascalabc.net

Помогите пожалуйста решить данную задачу на Паскале. Ну или можно и на js.

Мой код (Pascal ABC):

```
program romb;
uses crt, graphwpf;
var x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4, scale, cx, cy: integer; a,b,c,d: real;
begin
SetMathematicCoords(-10,10,-9.2);
  drawgrid;
  cx := trunc(window.Width / 2);
  cy := trunc(window.Height / 2);
  Window.Title := 'Задача 1. Определение ромба по координатам';
  write('Введите x1, y1: '); readln(x1, y1);
  write('Введите x2, y2: '); readln(x2, y2);
  write('Введите x3, y3: '); readln(x3, y3);
  write('Введите x4, y4: '); readln(x4, y4);
  if ((x1 <> 0) and (x2 <> 0) and (x3 <> 0) and (x4 <> 0)) then
  begin
    scale := 30;
    moveTo(cx,cy);
    Polygon(Arr((x1, y1),(x2 ,y2),(x3, y3), (x4, y4)),RGB(255,228,196));
    a := trunc(sqrt(sqr(x2-x1)+sqr(y2-y1)));
    b := trunc(sqrt(sqr(x3-x2)+sqr(y3-y2)));
    c := trunc(sqrt(sqr(x4-x3)+sqr(y4-y3)));
    d := trunc(sqrt(sqr(x1-x4)+sqr(y1-y4)));
    write('A = ',a);
    write(' B = ',b);
    write(' C = ',c);
    write(' D = ',d);
    writeln('');
    if ((a = b) and (b = c) and (c = d)) then
      if ((x1 <> x2) and (x3 <> x4)) then 
      begin
        writeln('Это ромб!');
      end
      else writeln('Это квадрат')
    else if (
              ((x1 = x2) and (x2 = x3) and (x3 = x4))
            or 
              ((y1 = y2) and (y2 = y3) and (y3 = y4))
            or 
              ((x1 = y1) and (x2 = y2) and (x3 = y3) and (x4 = y4))
            )
      then
      begin
        textbackground(1);
        clrscr;
        writeln('Это прямая линия!':50)
      end
    else 
      begin
        textbackground(5);
        clrscr;
        writeln('Это четырехугольник, но не РОМБ!');
        writeln('Так как стороны не равны!');
      end;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как известно, [векторное произведение векторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), лежащих на параллельных прямых(или коллинеарных) равно нулю, соответственно Вам необходимо проверить векторные произведения векторов, образуемых противоположными ребрами, на равенство нулю.

Затем необходимо проверить перпендикулярность диагоналей c помощью [скалярного произведения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)